# Create Datatable from a list of column values

Tags: c#, datatable

I am trying to create a datatable from the following lists

```
**List1**
1
2
3
4
5

**List2**
foo1
foo2
foo3
foo4
foo5
```

The final table should look like this (name of the col doens't matter)

```
SomeName1   SomeName2
1           foo1
2           foo2
3           foo3
4           foo4
5           foo5
```

I am trying to avoid referring respective indexes of both the lists and adding them as rows

is there a better way of doing this?

EDIT:
I can have any number of lists not just 2

Comment: `Dictionary<Key, Value>` could be better option if you are looking for key,value pair item.

Comment: This datatable will be used eventually for some already existing UI rendering , can't change to dictionary

Comment: Then what did you try to convert these list to datatable. Please show your efforts as well..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will deal with any number of IEnumerable.

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var list1 = new List<int>(new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 });
    var list2 = new List<string>(new[] { "foo1", "foo2", "foo3", "foo4", "foo5" });
    var list3 = new List<bool>(new[] {true, false, true, true, false});

    var dt = MakeDataTable(list1, list2, list3);

    Console.ReadLine();

}

private static DataTable MakeDataTable(params IEnumerable[] lists)
{
    var dt = new DataTable();
    for (var i = 0; i < lists.Length; i++)
    {
        dt.Columns.Add("column" + i);
    }
    foreach (var data in CombineList(lists))
    {
        dt.Rows.Add(data);
    }

    return dt;
}

private static IEnumerable<object[]> CombineList(params IEnumerable[] lists)
{
    var enumerators = lists.Select(l=>l.GetEnumerator()).ToArray();
    while (enumerators.All(e => e.MoveNext()))
    {
       yield return enumerators.Select(e => e.Current).ToArray();
    }
}
```

Comment: What if i have more than 2 lists? The number of lists are not known at compile time

Comment: That's important information.  I've update the answer to account for that.

Comment: this works perfectly but i am still not sure what how the yield keyword in CombineList() function works . Can you kindly explain?

Comment: I'll give it my best shot.  The method has to return back IEnumerable<> for yield return.  It says when someone is looping over the enumeration I want to give these values back.  It's easier than creating a list or array to store everything then returning it in one shot.  Also if someone stop part way the code stops as well so it's not as much overhead.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
public DataTable GetTable(List list1, List list2)
{
 DataTable table = new DataTable();
 table.Columns.Add("SomeName1", typeof(int));
 table.Columns.Add("SomeName2", typeof(string));
 var collection = list1.Join(list2, x => x, y => y, (x, y) => new { X = x, Y = y });
 foreach ( var row in collection) 
   {
    table.Rows.Add(row.x, row.y);
   }
 return table;
  }
```